# Accept arguments in python from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to Python so please excuse me if this is a naïve question. I'm having a running python script which accepts two parameters to be passed during run time.

`python code.py X Y`

X and Y are the variables which I pass during runtime when I execute the python script

Now I have saved these variables in a text file (names.txt)

x,y

a,b

c,d

How can I pass these variables in the python script during runtime in a loop and it should exit when records are reached EOF. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could read the contents of the file (line-by-line) in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.
I've managed to do it using below.

```
with open(r'C:\Shashank\_SK\test\InputDate.txt', 'r') as file:
types = (line.split(",") for line in file)
xys = ((type[0], type[1]) for type in types)
for x, y in xys:
   print(x,y)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it from the python script you can do it like this:

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    data.split(',')

for i in data():
    yourfunction(data[0], data[1])
```

This works if the words in names.txt is separated by commas

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The names in the files are in commas. I tried as you suggested but getting below error.     data.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'